# merging dataframe does not give any result with inner join

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframe namely accidents_data which has 15 columns and bad_air_quality_districts dataframe whch has 2 columns.[accidents_data image[][1]][bad_air_quality_districts]

now i want to join both dataframes on column 'District Name' and finally keep only the data from accidents_data whose districts name matches with the district name of bad_air_quality_districts.
[image: accidents_data]
[image: bad_air_quality_districts]
I tried merging both the dataframes using the below line but it does not show any results.

enter code here

```
pd.merge(accidents_data, bad_air_quality_districts, on='District Name', how='inner')
```

Kindly advise!

Comment: You got an empty dataframe out of the merge?

Comment: @kerwei yes, i got an empty dataframe

Comment: Could it be due to whitespaces messing up the join keys?

Comment: @kerwei I think you are right, i stripped the spaces and the inner join worked. Thanks for suggesting it! :)